# Rails 3 inline datatable CRUD

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datatable, crud

I've been trying to put together a CRUD interface for a datatable in a rails project and I'm completely at a loss of how to go about this. I've previously put together AJAX/jQuery CRUD interfaces and had them working easily, but when it comes to being able to add/edit/remove rows I can't tell how to update the dataset and have the results show live on the table.

Can anyone point me towards documentation or examples where this has been done with rails 3?

Comment: does your database already exist are are you starting from scratch? Have you looked into `rails g scaffold` as a quick way to get rails to generate some code that will give you basic CRUD on a table as well as code that you can look at to figure out what's going on?

Comment: Whoops, forgot to specify there... I want the CRUD to all be via AJAX. If it were done with page reloads between, this would be quite simple.

This is on a well established code base and database.

Comment: okay - maybe try something like http://itshouldbeuseful.wordpress.com/2011/05/23/creating-ajax-forms-with-rails-3-and-jquery/

Comment: That's just a standard form, which I've already created. What I want is this sort of thing in a datatable which has sorting, searching, and pagination built in.

Comment: You have to watch for response and remove the row you want to be removed. You can accomplish this through jquery pretty easy. Try to write some code and show us. We will help you to modify it.

Comment: I've already tried doing it that way; the problem is that it only effects the markup, not the data set that the datatable is referencing, so if you click through the pagination buttons to a different page of results and then back, the changes are lost. I've since abandoned this approach entirely and have come up with a different solution to the requirement, one which doesn't involve the butchering of standards as this was going to lead to with the next step that was required.